# How to prevent Word 2010 (with EndNote X4+ installed) from spontaneously switching to draft view

Tags: microsoft-word-2010, endnote

The problem occurs in Word 2007 and EndNote X6 as well.

Answer (score 0):

It is a serious bug with not good solution. To mitigate do:

- do not use change tracking unless you have to
- if you have to use it, do not dwell in a comment

Answer (score 0):

A user, AndrewAcademic, on [this Microsoft Answers thread](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-word/word-keeps-randomly-switching-to-draft-view-when-i/67866da2-40c6-448c-91b5-e095f1638c6a?page=5) reports that he was told by EndNote that the problem arises if Instant Formatted is enabled alongside tracking changes.

These are the instructions they gave him:

> **To disable Instant Formatting in the current document:**
> **EndNote X1 and later:**
>
> 1. **Word 2002/2003/2004/2008/2011:** From the Tools menu in Word, go to the EndNote submenu and select Format Bibliography or Bibliography
>      Settings.
>    **Word 2007/2010:** On the EndNote tab, in the
>      Bibliography group, click the bottom corner arrow.
> 2. Click the Instant Formatting tab.
> 3. Click Turn Off to toggle Instant Formatting.  Click Cancel which will save changes to the Instant Formatting settings and not format
>      the document.
>
> Basically you can leave the instant formatting turned off until the
>   very end when the document is in Final form NOT showing Markup. Then
>   update the citations and bibliography.

Answer (score 0):

Very annoying problem with no real fix.  I have tried all the suggestions and the only ones that work are also the most impractical making them more or less useless.  The only "fix" I am aware of, which is the least painless, it to not leave the cursor on tracked changes.  If you leave in on regular text, the document stays on the regular view.  Not a fix, but it avoids the view change and the need to re-find your place int he document.

Comment: Was this not already mentioned in the answer by the person that asked the question?